# ClassNotFoundException for java.awt.image.BufferedImage on Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, classnotfoundexception, iplimage

I'm getting the title error in my program, and am a bit confused as to why. I have a program that uses `IplImages`, and up until now it has been working fine. I'm trying to use multithreading now though, and when I try to use the `IplImage class` in my `MyThread class` (which extends Thread), I'm getting this on the debug screen:
[image]

The code I'm using is:

```
IplImage imageToProcess = cvLoadImage(fileLocation);
```

Now, that code works just fine when I'm calling it in the `MainActivity class`, but seems to break when I call it in `MyThread.`

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Android does not have most of the awt classes it only has 2 classes from java.awt.font

See the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

There are also other pitfalls like no full support of the java.beans package.

I would recommend to set a breakpoint where the BufferedImage is successfully loaded and then analyse the class loader that loaded the BufferedImage. Hopefully it is a URLClassLoader and you can find out the resource that provides tha java.awt.ButteredImage.

Then set an exception breakpoint to ClassNotFoundException and try the code that fails. Go back in the stacktrace to the place where the class loading got triggered from and also analyse this class loader.

Comment: Do you know why it works in one class, but not in another? That's what's really confusing me here...

Comment: Yeah, it's basically an image variable in OpenCV (http://opencv.jp/opencv-2svn_org/cpp/core_basic_structures.html), and I'm using the JavaCV libraries (https://code.google.com/p/javacv/). Using it isn't ideal, but as I've said, I have this working in MainActivity. It's just when I try to pass it to a thread that I get the ClassNotFoundException.